# Jest coverage report in html missing coverage values

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage

I am unit testing my ReactJS app with Jest and have added configuration to get the code coverage. The coverage works well on cli but when I try to export coverage report as html the values corresponding to each file are not shown in the report. Here is my jest.config.json:

```
{
    "roots": [
        "test"
    ], 
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": ["text","html"],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/coverage/"
}
```

And here is my report generated in coverage folder inside index.html file:

[image]

As can be seen the numbers are missing. What coud be the reason when the text report has correct values shown as well. It happens only with html report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this as well.  Updating the package `istanbul-reports` to the latest version (3.0.0 at the time) fixed the issue.

Comment: One can use `npm list istanbul-reports` to see what other libraries are referencing this library, and update those libraries accordingly

Comment: @David Lozzi
 how to upgrade istanbul-reports dependencies

Comment: updating istanbul-reports to latest doesnt seem to work.  using jest: 23.1.0. node v8.10.0. using legacy.